# getting error while creating table and insert data in hbase

Tags: hbase, mapr

I have started the hbase using ./bin/hbase shell and in hbase shell im started creating table using

```
create '/user/mapr/newtable2', wwww
```

but at that time its showing error as

```
ERROR: Table must have at least one column family
```

Then while adding data into the table using

```
put 'newtable','2','countrydetail:city','chennai'
```

but it's also showing error as

```
ERROR: Failed 1 action: newtable: 1 time
```

data's are not inserting into the table. Please refer the below images.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your HBase table create command should be

```
create '<table_name>', '<column_family_name>'
```

In your case, as you have **`special characters`** in your table name it will give the ERROR

```
ERROR: Illegal character code:47, </> at 0. User-space table qualifiers may only contain 'alphanumeric characters' and digits: /user/mapr/newtable2
```

[image]

try to use **`alphanumeric characters`** in your table names and column qualifier names

Comment: Hi Prasad,  while creating new table i have used "create 'table123', 'food'" this command but im getting error as "ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null", Actually im working on 3 VM setup with MapR, 1-masterVM and 2 slaves VM. in master VM i have configured regionserver(by giving 3 VM hostnames) then keeping 2 slaves in backupmasters file at Master VM.

Comment: @VaasirNisaar looks like there is some issue in your cluster configuration, try to connect with your administrator to resolve the issue

Comment: Now the tables are created perfectly but adding the data into the table is not working, i have used the " hbase(main):002:0> put 'newtable', 'row1', 'countrydetail:city', 'Ooty' " there is no message and nothing shows jus simply its Idle.....

Comment: hbase(main):001:0> list
Listing HBase tables. Specify a path or configure namespace mappings to list M7                                                                                         tables.
TABLE
0 row(s) in 0.2010 seconds

=> []
hbase(main):002:0> list '/user/mapr'
TABLE
/user/mapr/table123
/user/mapr/newtable2
/user/mapr/newtable
3 row(s) in 0.1680 seconds

=> ["/user/mapr/table123", "/user/mapr/newtable2", "/user/mapr/newtable"]
hbase(main):003:0> put 'newtable', 'r1', 'countrydetail:city', 'Kerala'

Comment: using this command scan "<table_name> " also im getting same issue no response jus simply idle.........

Comment: It finally works by providing the table path-" put '/user/mapr/table123', 'row1', 'empdetails:Name', 'Vaasir' "